# How to refer Javascript file in HTML in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I have created two Javascript webresources with name **new_/Scripts/My.JSON2.js** and  **new_/Script/My.RestOperations.js** which contains namespace called MYTEST. And in the same place I created one html page to load when sitemap item is clicked, with name **new_/Webpages/My.sitemapPage.htm**. And I'm trying to call some JSON functions from JScript in html page which are present in "new_/Scripts/My.RestOperations.js" file under MYTEST namespace.
In html page I added reference to JScript files as below:

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javscript src="../Scripts/My.RestOperations.js"></SCRIPT>   
<SCRIPT type=text/javscript scr="../Scripts/My.JSON2.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javscript>
function=pageOnLoad()
{
 MYTEST.retrieveMultiple(dataSet,filter,callBackSuccess,callBackError);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

But still I'm getting an error as:

> 'MYTEST' is undefined.

Comment: Also, either use the correct spelling of `type=text/javascript` or remove the attribute altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) of the parent window by using `window.parent`.

```
window.parent.MYTEST.retrieveMultiple(dataSet,filter,callBackSuccess,callBackError);
```

If you try to execute code in the webresource before the load of the parent window's javascript file, you'll have to also put in a try/catch block to handle the fact that the parent file hasn't been loaded.

```
try {
    var check = window.parent.MYTEST;
} catch (e) {
    setTimeout(function () { pageOnLoad(); }, 1000);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps.

1. Find the url of web resource which you want to refer for example
    `http://servername/organization/WebResources/scriptfile` (dont include extention js if it             was not shown in url)
2. Put that url into html page relatively i.e. If html file also in WebResources folder then only  `<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptfile"></script>` will work.

Note the key is not put any thing extra which is not shown in resource url when you open it from your solution not even extension.